# CSS Animation hangs/stumbles

Tags: css, animation

I have a simple css animation, you can visit it here (the round circle): 
https://test.heraresidenzen.de/
The Element has position: fixed. The problem is that the animations hangs and stumbles. I have added a delay so that the animation starts after the page is rendered. But it is still stumbling when I'm scrolling during the animation.

```
.roll-in {
  animation: 2s linear 0s 1 animation;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

@keyframes animation {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    left: 110%;
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-720deg);
    left: 0px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve] in the question itself - see [something on my website doesn't work, can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: Works fine on my end. (iMac 27", Safari 13 and Google Chrome 79)

Comment: Works Fine may be some cache issue